# Trying to install Move (movelang.org) using npm, but it's not being added to #!/usr/bin/env

Tags: amazon-ec2, move

I'm trying to test [Rasumus Andersson's](httpS://github.com/rsms) [ec2-webapp](httpS://github.com/rsms/ec2-webapp/) but it is all scripted in [Move](https://github.com/rsms/move) and I'm having trouble getting Move working.

I installed it with 'npm install move' per the [instructions](https://github.com/rsms/move#readme), but when I try to run a Move script (like ec2-webapp/bin/myapp-httpd/mv), I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/env: move: No such file or directory
```

When I change the shebang in that script to a direct link to the move installation (#!/var/ec2-webapp/src/node/node_modules/move/bin).

```
-bash: bin/myapp-httpd.mv: /var/ec2-webapp/src/node/node_modules/move/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I'm not sure how to get Move into env correctly, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was just following the same tutorial by Rasumus Andersson and ran into the very same problem.

When you install npm modules, you can install them locally or globally.
http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

When I installed move globally, the error went away:

```
sudo npm -g install move
```